# How to solve this definite integral explicitly including a complex variable?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, classical-mechanics

The configuration of the following problem/integral is based on the fig 1 below. The area of the wedge with thickness $\Delta$ is from $-\infty$ to $-a$, which is non-analytical. From $-a$ to $a$ along the x-axis is the crack (void) area, which is also non-analytical. So, the entire red area is non-analytical. Outside of this red area is analytical.
[image]
When I read this problem, I found they gave the solution of the following integral directly (arrowed). I have no idea how they solved it explicitly.
[image]
**My question is how to get this:**
$$\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{1}{z-t} \sqrt{\frac{a-t}{a+t}}dt=\pi(1-\sqrt{\frac{z-a}{z+a}})$$
where $a>0$, $z=x+iy$ is a complex variable.

This integral/problem is on page 154 of Tada, H., Ernst, H. & Paris, P. Westergaard stress functions for displacement-prescribed cracks-II. Extension to mixed problems. Int J Fract 67, 151–167 (1994). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00019601.

Comment: Rui, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is a very low-quality question.

Comment: Sorry for that. I've already updated my post.

Comment: Have you tried substituting? Something like $y=\sqrt{\frac{a-x}{a+x}}$ might just do the trick

Comment: I think you've omited the square root. The integral has to be $\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{1}{z-t} \sqrt{\frac{a-t}{a+t}}dt=\pi(1-\sqrt{\frac{z-a}{z+a}})$

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've already updated.